# How can I make a chat script in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, networking, irc

I want to make a chat script in bash and I've started out pretty basic and you start off by login in with any name you want, no password required and then you can write commands like connect, clear, exit and so on.

But I want to be able to actually start a chat between two people in the terminal window. Now, I've read a little about IRC but I don't know how to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ver=1.0
my_ip="127.0.0.1"

function connect()
{

echo -n "Ip-address: "
read ip

if [ -n "$ip" ]
then

exit

fi    

}

function check()
{

    if [ "${c}" = "connect" ] || [ "${c}" = "open" ]
    then

    connect

    fi

    if [ "${c}" = "clear" ] || [ "${c}" = "cls" ]
    then

    clear
    new

    fi

    if [ "${c}" = "quit" ] || [ "${c}" = "exit" ]
    then

    echo "[Shutdown]"
    exit

    fi

}

function new()
{

    echo -n "$: "
    read c

    if [ -n "${c}" ]
    then

    check

    else

    echo "Invalid command!"
    new

    fi

}

function onLogin()
{

clear
echo "Logged in as ${l_name} on [${my_ip}]"
new

}

function login()
{

echo -n "Login: "
read l_name

if [ -n "${l_name}" ]

then
onLogin

else

echo "Invalid input!"
login

fi

}


#execution
clear
echo "Bash Chat v${ver} | Mac"
login
```

Comment: IRC is a protocol. You can write code that speaks it in whatever you would like but I'm not sure how that's related to any of the code you've already written. Also there are likely hundreds of thousands of irc clients out there already. Are you actually interested in writing an irc client in a shell script?

Comment: Well, not necessarily an irc-client, but something that would allow two users or more to connect through some internet protocol or something similar and then be able to send messages to each other.

Comment: A shell script *can* do this but likely really isn't the right choice for it. It is going to make many things quite complicated I would think.

Comment: Okay, is there any other way around this?

Comment: I'd at least like it to be run from the terminal.

Comment: There are any number of console irc clients. Predating any of that there's the venerable [`talk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_%28software%29) software. There's any number of things you can already use to chat with someone from a terminal if you aren't actively interested in writing your own client for something.

Comment: Okay, I've figured out how to chat with netcat so I think I'll build something with netcat. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to write a chat client in pure bash, it would have to be local chat (same physical machine) rather than network chat.

Assuming that this is adequate for your needs, you can use [named pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash) (FIFO)

### Illustration

Here is an example that illustrates what you can do with two pipes (for bidirectional communication):

1. mkfifo /tmp/chatpipe1 ; mkfifo /tmp/chatpipe2
2. (In terminal one):  cat > /tmp/chatpipe1
3. (In terminal two):  cat /tmp/chatpipe2

( same and in reverse for Terminals 3 and 4 )

[image: Illustrated chat session]

This illustrates that you can have 4 processes in bash, two writing to two pipes and two reading from the same two pipes.  Two terminals on the left are for Bob, two on the right are for John.

You can organize all of this into a single script if you understand bash backgrounding, loops (and hopefully traps to clean up on shutdown).

### Script

Here is a rudimentary version:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$2" ] ; then
    echo "Need names of chat pipes (yours and other's), eg $0 bob john"
    exit 1
fi

P1=/tmp/chatpipe${1}
P2=/tmp/chatpipe${2}

[ -p "$P1" ] || mkfifo $P1
[ -p "$P2" ] || mkfifo $P2

# Background cat of incoming pipe,
# also prepend current date to each line)
(cat $P2 | sed "s/^/$(date +%H:%M:%S)> /" ) &

# Feed one notice and then STDIN to outgoing pipe
(echo "$1 joined" ; cat) >> $P1

# Kill all background jobs (the incoming cat) on exit
trap 'kill -9 $(jobs -p)' EXIT
# (Probably should delete the fifo files too)
```

And a chat session:
[image: Chat session with script]

**Note** that this script is only a simple example.  If bob and john are different unix accounts, you'll have to be more careful with file permissions (or if you don't care about security, **mkfifo -m 777 ...** is an option)

Comment: Network chat is certainly possible by redirecting from/to `/dev/tcp/$host/$port` or via `nc`.

Answer (score -2):

A chatroom can be made in literally 10 lines of bash. I posted one on my github earlier today

https://github.com/ErezBinyamin/webCatChat/blob/master/minimalWbserver

Can handle “n” users. They just need to connect to :1234

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /tmp/webCat && printf "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<!doctype html><h2>Erez's netcat chat server!!</h2><form>Username:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\"><br>Message:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"message\"><div><button>Send data</button></div><button http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=129.21.194:1234\">Refresh</button></form>" > /tmp/webCat/webpage
while [ 1 ]
do
    [[ $(head -1 /tmp/webCat/r) =~ "GET /?username" ]] && USER=$(head -1 /tmp/webCat/r | sed 's@.*username=@@' | sed 's@&message.*@@') && MSG=$(head -1 /tmp/webCat/r | sed 's@.*message=@@' | sed 's@HTTP.*@@')
    [ ${#USER} -gt 1 ] && [ ${#MSG} -gt 1 ] && [ ${#USER} -lt 30 ] && [ ${#MSG} -lt 280 ] && printf "\n%s\t%s\n" "$USER" "$MSG" && printf "<h1>%s\t%s" "$USER" "$MSG" >> /tmp/webCat/webpage
    cat /tmp/webCat/webpage | timeout 1 nc -l 1234 > /tmp/webCat/r
    unset USER && unset MSG
done
```